# Which approach is best to get decimal value between Regex and % (mod)?

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I'm working for several years in financial market and from times to times I need to treat specifically the decimal part of a value. When I get the value as a `string` I use to use `Regex` and when I get the value as a `double` or a `decimal` I use to use `%`, ceiling and pow.

```
// with math operations to get a truncated int value from the decimal part
// of a decimal or double
(int)Math.Ceiling((value % 1) * Math.Pow(10D, (double)(decimalLength - 1)))

// with Regex to get a truncated string value from the decimal part
// of a string
Regex.Replace(value, @"^[^.]+\.([0-9]{" + decimalLength.ToString() + "}).*$", "$1")
```

The question, as described at the headline, witch one is best? Should I convert my `double` or `decimal` values to `string` and always use `Regex`? Maybe I should convert my `string` to `double` and always use math operations? Or am I doing great dealing this way?

Comment: first one is the preferred method.

Comment: No need for regex here, unless you want to make your code unreadable.

Comment: I wonder what answer is expected. `Use #1`? :) Tastes differ.

Comment: I reckon Regex method would be slower

Comment: If you are trying to get the left or right part of the `decimal`, another option would be to convert it to a string and then split the string on the decimal point. The issue with this is precision, if the wrong format specifier is used.

Comment: Thank you guys! Next time I need to get the decimal part of a string I'll convert it to decimal and use math operations ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to use mathematical function to perform mathematical operations.
Not only does it make the code more readable, it's also likely to have better performance.
Therefor, as [stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) wrote in the comments -  `Use #1` :).

Also, your regular expression does not take into consideration that different cultures might have different decimal separators.
Not everyone is writing one and a quarter as `1.25`, some cultures use `,` as the decimal separator and thus it's written as `1,25`.
Should you encounter a decimal like that, your regular expression will not work as you expect.

Comment: I live and work in Brazil and here we use `,` as decimal separator. The code I posted is an example were I know the decimal format. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another (quite easy method) which I'm sure people will state is *bad* or something (out of ignorance, mostly) is to convert it to a `string` and then split the string on the decimal point.

You can easily get the left and right parts of the `decimal` value in this manner, though it is not going to have the performance of the mathematical operations.

The nice thing of this method is that you don't need to use `Math.Pow` to get the `decimal` as a number that large, you can handle that in the `.ToString` portion.

```
int decimalPlaces = 10;
decimal number = 123456789.1234567890M;
string[] parts = number.ToString("F" + decimalPlaces).Split(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]);
long[] lParts = new long[parts.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    lParts[i] = Convert.ToInt64(parts[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(lParts[i].ToString());
```

Output:

```
123456789
1234567890
```

I'm not saying this is always the answer, but it can most certainly have it's advantages. It's also quite simple to use: all you have to do is change the `10` in the `decimalPlaces` to the number of decimal places you want, and you will have your same value. (Which of course, your method is just as modular.)

Merely putting this out here as another alternative to your methods, really the only **bad** method is using a `Regex`. If you wish to use `strings` then use regular string manipulation.

Update: Also, I just did a few benchmarks, on the `Math` method vs this `string` method, and found that the `Math` method *can* return *slightly* inaccurate results. When tested with `double number = 9.1234567890D;` the `string` method returned `1234567890`, whereas the `Math` method returned `1234567891`. This is something to keep in mind if you need the **absolute and exact** decimal values. The other issue is that the `Math` method cannot use a `decimal` type (which has greater precision than a `double` type) implicitly, it must be converted to a `double` first. The `string` method is, however, slower. It takes 250-300% of the time of the `Math` method.

These are just more things to keep in mind with it.

Comment: I usually need to get the decimal part when I'm working with positional data and most values are string at the end. It is a nice approach too ;)

Comment: @MFedatto Well the problem with the **pure math** method is that you can get *slightly* inaccurate results, due to floating-point error.

Comment: I use to work with decimal and double and the maximum precision I needed was 6 decimal positions, so it is not a significant problem working in .Net. I've experienced some of these issues working with JavaScript, witch have a terrible precision.